# Find the derivative of the function h(t) = (t^3/(t^7+3))^2

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, education

The problem is: $h(t) = (\frac{t^3}{(t^7+3)})^2$

I got as an answer [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdUn9.png) or 2\frac{t^3}{t^7+3}\left(\frac{\left(t^7+3\right)\left(3t^2\right)-7t^6}{\left(t^7+3\right)^2}\right) It was incorrect though.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I have no idea how to do it though, can't you post your answer on the page here?

Comment: I will try, but may take me a while

Comment: Check the second term (the one after the minus sign) in the numerator of the Quotient Rule -- something is missing there.

Comment: By the way, reposting the same question again is generally frowned upon here.

Comment: Sorry, I meant you probably can copy the original image and paste it and save your time. Now $h(t) = f(x)/g(x)$. then $h(t) = f(x)'(g(x))^{-1} + f(x)g(x)'(g(x)^{-2}$  So,  $h(t) = \frac{6t^5}{(t^7+3)^2} +\frac{ t^6*-2*{7t^6}}{(t^7 + 3)^3}$

Answer (score 0):

Apply the power so you have $$\frac {t^6}{(t^7+3)^2}$$
Then apply the quotient rule $$\frac{6t^5(t^7+3)^2-2(t^7+3)(7x^6)x^6}{(t^7+3)^4}$$
$$\frac{6t^5(t^7+3)^2-14t^{12}(t^7+3)}{(t^7+3)^4}$$